# Linear dependence and nonzero p-vectors

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

If a, b, and c are linearly dependent, then it's easy to show that $ a\wedge b\wedge c = 0$. However, if a, b, and c are linearly independent, how do you show that $ a\wedge b\wedge c \ne 0$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the universal property of an exterior power?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Presumably you know the first direction is easy to show because the $3$-ary wedge product is alternating and $3$-linear. The universal property, which follows from the construction of the wedge, says that *any* alternating $3$-linear map factors through it. In particular a determinant function on the span of 3 linearly independent vectors will factor through it. But we know the determinant function will be nonzero on those vectors, so the wedge must also be. (Some details omitted for brevity.)

Comment: You *might* find my [video](https://youtu.be/x4c_kAmKP9E) helpful on the connection to the determinant.

Comment: That was a very nice video. It's really good to have you on this SE.

Comment: In a less fancy way, extend $\{a,b,c\}$ to a basis for your vector space. Since $(a\wedge b\wedge c)\wedge (d\wedge\dots\wedge q) \ne 0$, we must have $a\wedge b\wedge c \ne 0$. (I sure prefer subscripts to list of letters. :D)